# What should I do if I suspect my account have been hacked?

Tags: support, accounts, security

Today when I log in to StackOverflow, I receive a message of `Suspicious request`. I did a search and I realised that might be caused by the Internet Service Provider assigning me a different IP address.

However, other than that I realised my account had possibly been browsed by others because I only view my `Reputation Tab` once in a while.

Just in my last log in, the reputation summary is showing something like "+400 reputation since last visit to reputation tab".

However, now it is gone and  possibly means someone might have logged in to my account and viewed it?

**Que:** I might be paranoid in this matter, but is there anything we can do if we suspect our account might have been compromised? Can I report this to the moderator for checking?

Comment: Change password?

Comment: @honk I already did, but I was thinking is there any way where I can report this to verify whether my account is indeed compromised. For example the moderator could probably check my account activity...etc?

Comment: You could flag one of your own posts and request that a moderator check your account for logins from different locations. Include a link to this post for context.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Will do, thanks for your advice.